# split array values into different divs

Tags: php, arrays, row, echo

I have a php array generated by Advanced custom field.
here is my php code:

```
<?php
$rows = get_field('nous_suivre',11 ); // get all the rows
print_r($rows)
?>
```

when I print_r my array, here is what I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nom] => Facebook
            [lien] => http://www.facebook.com/ID
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nom] => Twitter
            [lien] => http://www.twitter.com/ID
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [nom] => Instagram
            [lien] => http://www.instagram.com/ID
        )

)
```

what I'm trying to do is to split my array content into separate divs, without incrementation.

here is what I'm trying to get:

```
<div id="1"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/ID">Facebook<a></div> qsdjqslkdqjkg qsdhjqsd <div id="2"><a href="http://www.instagram.com/ID">Instagram<a></div>

div id="8"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/ID">Twitter<a></div>
```

in fact I need to echo wherever I want values from rows.
when reading on the net, I tried for example to get "Facebook", this:

```
<?php echo $row[0]->[nom]; ?> // get value "nom" from first row of "$row" table;
```

but it's not working.

Comment: examples should be in English, not in French

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'nom'=>'Facebook',
        'lien'=>'http://www.facebook.com/ID'
    ),
    array(
        'nom'=>'Twitter',
        'lien'=>'http://www.twitter.com/ID'
    ),
    array(
        'nom'=>'Instagram',
        'lien'=>'http://www.instagram.com/ID'
    ),
);

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    echo '<div id="'.($key+1).'"><a href="'.$value['lien'].'">'.$value['nom'].'</a></div>';
}
```

Result:

```
Facebook
Twitter
Instagram
```

HTML Result :

```
<div id="1"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/ID">Facebook</a></div>
<div id="2"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/ID">Twitter</a></div>
<div id="3"><a href="http://www.instagram.com/ID">Instagram</a></div>
```

---

---

**EDIT** (after the comments):

```
$new_data = array();

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $new_data[$value['nom']] = $value;
}

echo $new_data['Facebook']['nom'].' => '.$new_data['Facebook']['lien'].'<br />';

var_dump($new_data);
```

Result:

```
Facebook => http://www.facebook.com/ID

array (size=3)
  'Facebook' => 
    array (size=2)
      'nom' => string 'Facebook' (length=8)
      'lien' => string 'http://www.facebook.com/ID' (length=26)
  'Twitter' => 
    array (size=2)
      'nom' => string 'Twitter' (length=7)
      'lien' => string 'http://www.twitter.com/ID' (length=25)
  'Instagram' => 
    array (size=2)
      'nom' => string 'Instagram' (length=9)
      'lien' => string 'http://www.instagram.com/ID' (length=27)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I can't use incrementation, I really need to echo freely every results. I need to echo "facebook" for example inside a div, and twitter inside another, without knowing the div id. do you inderstand ?

Comment: Ok, i see. Tell me please if is correct the structure of the array provided in my answer

Comment: I guess so. the only thing I can tell you is the print_r result I've included in my message, what else do you need ?

Comment: I 'm not sure that i have understood you very well but i updated my answer.