# What is the easiest way of splitting data in 2 divs?

Tags: php, html

Acutually the easiest way is for sure CSS but I want to know how to do this with PHP.
This below is an example:

```
$html .= "<div class='column1'>";
$html .= "<ul>";
foreach($options as $option){$html .= "<li>" . $option['framework'] . "</li>";}
$html .= "</ul>";
$html .= "</div>";
```

Lets say that the loop has 10 options

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5

How can I get the rest of the 5 options in another div?

```
$html .= "<div class='column2'>";
$html .= "<ul>";
$html .= "<li>what to put here?</li>";
$html .= "</ul>";
$html .= "</div>";
```

- 6
- 7
- 8
- 9
- 10

Comment: revise the codes to that the 2nd part will be rendered and used after the system show half of the data items.

Comment: look it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595025/split-array-values-into-different-divs

Answer (score 0):

Although not beautiful, I would probably land on something like the following. However this relies on the fact that you know the list needs to be 5 a piece, so maybe that's what you want.

```
  $options = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j");
  $newList = 5;
  $endList = 9; 

  foreach ($options as $key => $value) { 
    if( $key == 0){
        $html .= "<div class='column1'><ul>";
    }
    if( $key == $newList){
        $html .= "</ul></div>";
        $html .= "<div class='column2'><ul>";
    }
    $html .= "<li>" . $value . "</li>";
    if( $key == $endList){
        $html .= "</ul></div>";
    }
  }
  
  echo $html;
```